# Are there any famous/notable mathematicians who have their own YouTube channel?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

Are there any famous/notable mathematicians who have their own YouTube channel?

I found this amazing  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTnEG_WGd2Q&t=7s) regarding the book.
The YouTube channel name is **The Math Sorcerer**,
but I don't know what the background of The Math Sorcerer is. From the analysis of the video I think he is a famous/notable mathematician.

I want to know more about YouTube channels of notable mathematicians.

Comment: Vi Hart and 3Blue1Brown come to mind.

Comment: Richard E Borcherds'  [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIyDqfi_cbkp-RU20aBF-MQ)

Comment: I don't know if the owner is a known mathematician, but what about NumberPhile?

Comment: It doesn't seem easy to find out "The Math Sorcerer"'s real name. All of the books in the video you mentioned are at the undergraduate level. It's very unlikely that person is notable in the way Borcherds (a Fields medalist) is notable if that's what you're wondering about. (That's not a judgement on the content either way--I haven't reviewed it at all.)

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Numberphile is run by Brady Haran, who is not a mathematician. However, the presenters in Numberphile videos are often famous mathematicians!

Comment: I love the Math Sorcerer, who is a really humble guy who loves math and is an excellent teacher. He's not famous as a researcher, but he's becoming famous as a teacher because of his humble fun YouTube videos.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Neither is a mathematician per se.

Comment: This is a tough question to answer because there are probably hundreds of math Youtube channels spearheaded/represented by a single personality, and your example of The Math Sorcerer isn't famous/notable as a researcher, so it's not clear how people should answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are some YouTube channels of mathematicians that I really enjoy. Their levels of fame and notoriety vary, from PhD students at one end to Dr. Borcherds (a fields medalist) at the other. Presented in no particular order:

- [Alvaro Lozano-Robledo](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsl3cpHnDaFTYnV66g8MB0A) -- Recordings of a graduate course on elliptic curves, some videos about algebra for kids, and more!
- [Paul VanKoughnett](https://www.youtube.com/user/allispaul) -- Recordings of a currently-running seminar on stable homotopy theory.
- [Richard Borcherds](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIyDqfi_cbkp-RU20aBF-MQ) -- Dr. Borcherds is uploading new content at an incredible pace on various undergraduate- and graduate-level topics.
- [Michael Penn](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6jM0RFkr4eSkzT5Gx0HOAw) -- Mostly videos about solving contest-style problems.
- [Daniel Litt](https://www.youtube.com/user/dalitt88) -- Recordings of a graduate course on étale cohomology, among other things.
- [Billy Woods](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcNQgs6bKds_KBpjp2_oavw) -- Has a lovely series of videos on algebraic number theory.
- [Boarbarktree](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeIEAkqvS4fJMTwUtF4OFw) -- Currently just 3 videos, on homology. I look forward to more!
- [Kristaps John Balodis](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRXC6M65qiFlHaXGDNC--VA) -- Videos on number theory, geometry, set theory, and more, as well as interesting interviews with current math PhD students!

I'll also take this opportunity to plug [my own YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZBdyzX1GY6bXfnjjBNDeNg). Currently the content there is sparse and not of the highest quality, but I aim to improve over time! Here's a [30-second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSnRzNtuuk4) I made on computing $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f^{-1}(x)$, which I'm quite happy with.

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate the central lecture course from

- *[The WE-Heraeus International Winter School on Gravity and Light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G4SqIboeig&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_)* by *[Frederic P. Schuller](https://people.utwente.nl/f.p.schuller?tab=research)*.

He formidably presents in $28$ lectures, each roughly one and a half hour long the mathematical foundations necessary to understand general relativity. The lectures are built around the definition of the term **spacetime**, defined as

**Spacetime** is a four-dimensional topological manifold with a smooth atlas carrying a torsion-free connection compatible with a Lorentzian metric and a time orientation satisfying the Einstein equations.

Answer (score 5):

Field medalist and Abel Prize winner **Timothy Gowers**

You tube channel [link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQwRDS6_J4OY4FohFvee5PQ)

Answer (score 5):

- **Insights into Mathematics**: [by N J Wildberger](https://www.youtube.com/c/njwildberger/about)

Answer (score 4):

Daily Challenge with [Po-Shen Loh](https://www.youtube.com/c/DailyChallengewithPoShenLoh/about)

[Math-life balance](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYRR0SgbYH59htIHkwTbqMw/featured) by Prof .Mura Yakerson Phd in algebraic geometry and  postdoc at ETH Zurich Switzerland

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that I have found named [Eddie Woo](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCq0EGvLTyy-LLT1oUSO_0FQ).

His most popular videos define the case of $0$ in mathematics and some others and I suggest you watch them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to reveal The Math Sorcerer's real name if it seems he's trying to hide it but he was my professor in community college in Florida. He's still doing it so I don't want to doxx him. He's a legendary teacher at the college but a previous poster is right, it's undergraduate courses he mostly teaches. His homework videos specifically made for our class had the same voice and he linked us private videos from the Math Sorcerer youtube channel.